# Add 2 Delete ways in laravel Destroy Method (Laravel 5.3)

Tags: jquery, laravel

I am using jquery to Delete recordes i have 2 different jquery methods one is to Delete a single record which goes in Controller Destroy method  and other is to Delete Multiple records which goes in Controller destroyAll method 
I want to use only Destroy method for both in Controller where delete for single and multiple records boyh can handle and i am using resource Controller 
here my methods below

**for Single record jquery method**

```
function studentDelete(id) {
    if(confirm('Are you sure to delete this User!')) {
        $("#row_"+id).attr("style", "display:none");
        $.ajax({
            url: '/student/'+id,
            type: "DELETE",
            success: function(result) {
                if(result == 'delete') {
                    $('#message').show();
                    $('#message-text').html('successfully deleted.');
                    $('#message').removeClass('displayhide').addClass('alert alert-success display-show');
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**for Multiple records jquery method**

```
function deleteAll () {
        if(!$('input:checkbox:checked').length){
           alert("Nothing Selected");
           return false;
        }
        if(confirm('Are you sure!')) {
        var checkedValues = $('input:checkbox:checked').map(function() {
            return this.value;
        }).get();
        $.ajax({
        type    : "POST",
        url     : "{{ url('/school-management/student/destroyAll') }}",
        data    : {ids: checkedValues, _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}"},
        success: function(result) {
                        if(result == 'delete') {
                            window.location.href = "/dashboard";
                        }
                    }
    });

        }
    }
```

**Controller Method For Single Record**

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $student = Student::findOrFail($id);
    $student->delete();
    return 'delete';
}
```

**Controller Method For Single Record**

```
    public function destroyAll(Request $request)
{
    $ids = $request->input('ids');
    $school = Student::whereIn('id', $ids);
    $school->delete();
    session()->flash('msg',trans('deleted successfully.'));
    return 'delete';

}
```

**Route**

```
Route::resource('/student', 'SchoolController');
```

I want to use only a single method which is destroy to handle both one and multiple delete records 
I have idea but dont know how to use it
it is that just to check that request i coming from which method from studentDelete or from deleteAll

Answer (score 0):

Make a common function in controller to delete one or more records like, and its input parameter is an array like:

```
public function delete(Request $request)
{
    // here $request is an array that contains one or more id's into it
    if(count($request->input()) > 0)
    {
        foreach(($request->input() as $id)
        {
            // code to delete records
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your first ajax to

```
 $.ajax({
        type    : "POST",
        url     : "{{ url('/student/destroy') }}",
        data    : {ids: id, _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}"},
```

and your second

```
$.ajax({
        type    : "POST",
        url     : "{{ url('/student/destroy') }}",
        data    : {ids: checkedValues, _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}"},
```

and your destroy function to

```
public function destroy(Request $request)
{
    $ids = $request->input('ids');
    if (gettype($ids) == 'array') {
    $school = Student::whereIn('id', $ids);
    } else {
    $school = Student::findOrFail($id);
    }
    $school->delete();
    session()->flash('msg',trans('deleted successfully.'));
    return 'delete';

}
```